# Thymeleaf - how to display values of a Set inside a table's <td>?

Tags: html, set, thymeleaf

I want to show all of user profiles in a table that shows all users.

The userDTO has an attribute `private Set<UserProfile> profiles` that's passed onto the HTML to be rendered in a table's cell.

Since the Set is iterable, I'd like it to display the user profiles as:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center" th:text="#{user.ssoId}">ssoId</th>
            <th style="text-align: center" th:text="#{user.fullName}">firstName lastName</th>
            <th style="text-align: center" th:text="#{user.email}">email</th>
            <th style="text-align: center" th:text="#{user.state}">state</th>
            <th style="text-align: center" th:text="#{user.profile}">profile</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="pojo : ${pojoList}">
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${pojo.ssoId}" />
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${('pojo.firstName pojo.lastName')} " />
            <td style="text-align: center" th:text="${user.email}" />
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr style="text-align: center" th:each="profile : ${pojo.profile}" >
                        <td th:text="${profile.type}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I try this, it cries about the profile attribute not being public. It actually isn't, but making it public will solve this issue? How to show the user profiles properly?

Comment: It's unclear.. What is the problem? First, add getter\setter to `Set profile` and it will be ok. Second, what did you mean `how to how the user's profiles properly`? I think you have done it properly, you just need to set accessors for this field.

Comment: I believe I may have finished this question in a hurry. The userDTO class has all the getters and setters. So far, my application has only one user (master user) with all profiles defined. I want to show, in this table field, all profiles for the user. The `Set<UserProfile>` contains elements from an Enum that declares the values on a `String type` attribute. To my knowledge, the problem here lies in parsing the values from the Enum to the table.

Comment: Actually, the problem is not there, at least not yet! The basic problem is that the, even though I have only one user with three roles, my service layer is delivering on method `findAll()` three users with three roles each. Something is awry, regarding the mapping. I'll post another questions with more details.